# Kinect with turtlebot

Tags: kinect, rviz, pcl, turtlebot, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running kinect with turtle bot. The value of pointcloud(/camera/rgb/points) and value of("/scan")remains constant. I am not unable to visualize both laser scan and poincloud in rviz. In rviz it shows transformation is correct, it shows the number of messages received which keeps on increasing but in poincloud side panel it says [0] points displayed from [0] messages. The hardware is fine because i have used with different machine and it works fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53600/kinect-with-turtlebot.../) by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1610 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer of this question is explained here http://answers.ros.org/question/53592/pointcloud_to_laser-output-value-is-constant/

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0